# Is there a way to autojoin community chat when I log in?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm part of a community in Diablo 3 but when logging in, I often forget to click on the community button and then join the community's chat channel. Based on the low number of people I see in it, I'm guessing I'm not alone in this.

Is there any way to set it up so that I autojoin a community's channel when I start the game?

Comment: Doing a quick scan of options, I can't seem to find any that would allow you to autojoin.  And I can't find any mention of chat on Blizzard's page about the new features, except in passing.

Comment: not right now no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. I'm part of multiple communities. Sometimes I want to join a specific community at a certain time based on what I plan on doing. So if I want to rift, I join my rifting community. If I want to farm bounties, I join my split bounty community. Auto-joining one community for gear help or friends might come in the future, but there is no way of doing this as of yet.

EDIT: It has been updated and you now autojoin the community chat you were in when you left - WizLiz

Comment: It has been updated and you now autojoin the community chat you were in when you left, might want to update your answer ;)

Comment: @WizLiz There ya go! :)